# LuckyBackup scheduled backup does not work

Tags: backup, cron

I am using luckyBackup 0.4.8 on Kubuntu 15.04. I created a profile to backup my data files. When executing the profile manually everything works fine.

I also created a cron schedule to execute the backup automatically. The log file "/root/.luckyBackup/logs/-LastCronLog.log" is updated at the right time so obviously cron works correctly.

However new files are not copied so the backup itself does not work.

The log files named like "--20151107205001.log" (in the same folder) are NOT updated at the same date/time and were updated during manual execution last time.

In the "-LastCronLog.log" I can see some error "No protocol specified luckybackup: cannot connect to X server :0".

How can I make the backup work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about root user rights. The solution is to edit the profile schedule and to enable the console mode. See [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/luckybackup/discussion/873564/thread/ae438d18/#831a).